# tomcat filter mapping not working

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, servlet-filters

I've implemented login form and created access filter and added mapping to web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>AccessFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.app.editor.AccessFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AccessFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/editor/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher> 
</filter-mapping>
```

and it works fine when I run the code in Netbeans locally, but when I deploy to my web server - filter mapping not working. Both of the servers are Tomcat 6. Logs are OK - no errors.
I've tried to debug remotely and I see that AccessFilter class is init() is called, but actually doFilter() method not executed.

Can somebody give some hint on this problem, 'cause I've lost.

UPD:
  Here's complete web.xml, it's identical on both Tomcat - on local and remote.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>LoginServelet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.app.editor.LoginServelet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LoginServelet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <filter>
    <filter-name>AccessFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.app.editor.AccessFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>AccessFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/editor/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher> 
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Just wonder whether there're some tomcat options in server.xml that switches filter mappings on/off?

Comment: Can you share the complete web.xml from both the tomcat?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Are you sure you are testing with the good URL?

Comment: Not working, I mean when I do remote debug, doFilter() method not executed, but when I debug same code on localhost everything is fine and doFilter() is executed.